# Control when a ListBox opens or closes

Tags: gwt

When the user clicks on a ListBox I want to make an asynchronous call and populate it.
The problem is that the ListBox opens right away.
The asynchronous call will complete later.

It seems that there is no way to control when the ListBox opens or closes.

What I would like to is:

- Click on the ListBox.
- Get the data remotely.
- Display listbox pop up with data after the call completes.

I there a way to do this with a ListBox?

I know I can that I can write a widget that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to this with ListBox.